# How to prove $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb C \sqcup \mathbb C/\mathbb C^*$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C)$ be the complex projective line which is defined as $\mathbb C^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}/_\sim$ where $(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2)\Longleftrightarrow (x_2,y_2)=(\lambda x_1,\lambda y_1)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C^*=\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

**I need to show that $\mathbb P_1(\mathbb C)\cong \mathbb C \sqcup \mathbb C/_{\mathbb C^*}$ as varieties (or at least as topological spaces).**

First I would like to know what $\mathbb C \sqcup \mathbb C/_{\mathbb C^*}$ means? As I understand it is the space $(\mathbb C \times \{0\})\cup (\mathbb C \times \{1\})/_\sim$ where $(x,0)\sim(x,0), (x,1)\sim(x,1) \text{ and }(x_1,0)\sim(x_2,1) \Longleftrightarrow x_1=x_2\neq0$. If this is right then how would I explicitly define a map from one set to the other? Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: The usual notation is $P^1(C)$. But your definition is wrong; it is the quotient $(C^2 \setminus \{0\})/C^*$.

Comment: I believe the intention here is to glue two copies of the line along the punctured line.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg ah yes that was a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The equivalence you defined will not yields the projective line. Instead, you should consider $(x_1,0)\sim(x_2,1)\Leftrightarrow x_1=1/x_2$. Now show that the maps $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\sqcup_{\mathbb{C}^* }\mathbb{C}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x/y,0)$ if $y\neq 0$ and $(0,1)$ if $y=0$ is well defined, bijective and an homeomorphism.

Comment: @Roland, Thank you. I shall try this.